# How to customize the login avatar? I want to remove the circle that is automatically put around my picture

Tags: themes, login-screen

The default avatar looked really nice as a transparent ping outline of a person. It had no circle around it so I wanted to put a zergling as my avatar as transparent .png. Unfortunately it automatically places it inside a circle which defeated the purpose of the awesome transparency of the .png file.

Is there a way to customize the default theme?[avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QunzI.jpg)